# Pandas Dataframe - GroupBy key and keep max value on a another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to group a frame by key. For each group there could be :

1. one couple of id, where 'max registered' is a unique value I need to keep
2. two couples of id : id1-id2 and id2-id1 where I need to keep the max between their 'max registered' or one of them if their 'max registered' are equal and keep only one of the couples (because id1-id2 and id2-id1 should be considered as one couple, because we don't care about the order of the ids in a couple)
3. more than two couples of id : it could be combinations of case 1 = one couple, and case 2 = two couples. They need to be treated like case 1 and case 2 inside the same group of key.

Here is the original dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'first': ['A', 'B', 'A1', 'B1', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K'],
                   'second': ['B', 'A', 'B1', 'A1', 'D', 'C', 'F', 'E', 'H', 'G', 'J', 'L'],
                   'key': ['AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'CD', 'CD', 'EF', 'EF', 'GH', 'GH', 'IJ', 'KL'],
                   'max registered': [10, 5, 10, 5, 'NaN', 15, 10, 5, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 15]
                 })
df


    first   second  key max registered
0   A       B       AB  10
1   B       A       AB  5
2   A1      B1      AB  10
3   B1      A1      AB  5
4   C       D       CD  NaN
5   D       C       CD  15
6   E       F       EF  10
7   F       E       EF  5
8   G       H       GH  NaN
9   H       G       GH  NaN
10  I       J       IJ  NaN
11  K       L       KL  15
```

Here is what dataframe should look like once it as been grouped and (here comes my problem) aggregated/filtered/transformed/applied ? I don't know how to do it after grouping my data and what solution I should opt for.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'first': ['A', 'A1', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'I', 'K'],
                   'second': ['B', 'B1', 'C', 'F', 'H', 'J', 'L'],
                   'key': ['AB', 'AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH', 'IJ', 'KL'],
                   'max registered': [10, 10, 15, 10, 'NaN', 'NaN', 15]
                 })
df

    first   second  key max registered
0   A       B       AB  10
1   A1      B1      AB  10
2   D       C       CD  15
3   E       F       EF  10
4   G       H       GH  NaN
5   I       J       IJ  NaN
6   K       L       KL  15
```

I'm watching tutorials about groupby() and pandas documentation since 2 days without finding any clue of the logic behind it and the way I should do this. My problem is (as I see it) more complicated and not really related to what's treated in those tutorials (for example [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUgd48QYmfI) that I watched several times)

Comment: key=EF should be 10 not 5 IIUC

Comment: It's edited, thanks for the review, I'm a little bit tired about this problem ahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create ordered group from `first` and `second` columns. `key` is useless here since your want all max for each subgroup (max for (A,B) and max for (A1,B1)) then sort values by `max registered` by descending order. Finally group by this virtual groups and keep the first value (the max):

```
out = df.assign(group=df[['first', 'second']].apply(frozenset, axis=1)) \
        .sort_values('max registered', ascending=False) \
        .groupby('group').head(1).sort_index()
print(out)

   first second key  max registered     group
0      A      B  AB            10.0    (A, B)
2     A1     B1  AB            10.0  (B1, A1)
5      D      C  CD            15.0    (C, D)
6      E      F  EF            10.0    (E, F)
8      G      H  GH             NaN    (G, H)
10     I      J  IJ             NaN    (J, I)
11     K      L  KL            15.0    (K, L)
```

Comment: @Lemisourd. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it does ! I had to deal with my NA values, I don't know why but its not going well as my NaN are consider string (arent't NA values supposed to be a specific type ?) so the descending ordering doesn't work if I keep them in the data. Otherwise it look like it worked well ! I have more or less 7000 rows vs 14000 before this filter.